# Making the Game Over-screen appear when object goes off screen Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been googling like crazy as the newbie I am, hopefully someone here can give me an answer.
I've got an object (rigid body 2D) which triggers the Game Over-screen when it touches other rigid bodies, but if the object just falls off the screen the game keeps going without my game object.
Which code should I use to make the event "falling off screen" trigger the Game Over-screen?

Haven't found anything helpful while googling :(

Answer (score 0):

I can offer two ways of handling this function. You can match coordinates of object with Max-Min values in loop update, OR You can add Game-over trigger zones out of the borders of screen. For example:

```
bool isGameOver;
float xMaxValue = 10; // X value (or -X) of Your right/left screen borders
float yMaxValue = 15; // Y value of Your top screen border
float yMinValue = -5;// Y value of Your bottom screen border
private void Update() {
    Vector3 playerPos = transform.position;
    If (playerPos.x < -xMaxValue || playerPos.x > xMaxValue  ||
        playerPos.y < yMinValue || playerPos.y > yMaxValue ) {
        isGameOver = true;
    }
```

Or script on border zones (check their collaider component "Is trigger" checkboxes):

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) {
    // PlayerScriptName - name of script on Your player GameObject
    // Or You can compare tags, or use other approaches to check 
    // is triggered object a player
    if (col.gameObject.TryGetComponent<PlayerScriptName>
        (out PlayerScriptName playerScript)) {
        // In this case field isGameOver must have 
        // public access level (in PlayerScriptName class):
        playerScript.isGameOver = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Since my game objects only move up and down I'll see which one will be easiest to use :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that it fell from an environment and then show game over. You only need the following simple code.

```cs
[SerializeField]
private float fallYThreshold = -10; // Limit y fall
private void Update()
{
    if (transform.position.y <= fallYThreshold)
    {
        GameOver() //Run game over method here too
    }
}
```